# Keras tensorflow: InvalidArgumentError: Node 'IsVariableInitialized_2196'

Tags: keras, image-segmentation

I am trying to train a segmentation model, tried fit_generator and also on a single batch as:

autoencoder.fit(x,y)

x and y has shape same as of the model input and output, but it gives following error.

> InvalidArgumentError: Node 'IsVariableInitialized_2196': Unknown input
>   node 'batch_normalization_1/moving_mean/biased'

This error message generates in keras tensorflow during training a segmentation model. I have tried a naive model, the issue still exits.

The input of model is (128,128,3) image and output is its flattened segmentation i.e. (16384, 66) where there are 66 classes.

Comment: You might want to add some information about the model and its inputs.

Comment: input: (None, 128, 128, 3), image 
output: (None, 16384, 66), segmentation map - flattened